# MySQL: Update or Copy data from one table to another based on matching values

Tags: mysql

I am stumped on this one. I two tables:

**Distributor**

*category*         *cat_match_id*

Wallets
Shoes

**Categories**

*id*      *cat_name*
1       Wallets
2       Shoes

What I'm trying to do is search through the column *category* in each row in **Distributor** (thousands of rows), match that to the *cat_name* and take the associated id in **Categories** (112 rows), then take the id and place it in *cat_match_id*. I have search through every post I could find and have tried every solution, even combinations of solutions.

I have tried:

```
UPDATE Distributor
INNER JOIN Categories 
ON Distributor.category = Categories.cat_name
SET Distributor.category = Categories.id
```

And (tried with left, right, inner, outer, etc. joins)

```
UPDATE Distributor d
LEFT JOIN Categories c 
ON d.category = c.cat_name
SET d.cat_match_id = c.id
WHERE d.category = c.cat_name
```

Also using an example from [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html):

```
UPDATE Distributor,Categories 
SET Distributor.cat_match_id = Categories.id
WHERE Distributor.category = Categories.cat_name
```

Those are just a few of the probably dozen or more snippets that I have tried. Is it because I'm trying to match 2 varchars and copy over a resulting int?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initial query is almost correct, barring some problems with your data, except that you are updating the wrong column.   You should be doing this:

```
UPDATE Distributor d
INNER JOIN Categories c
    ON d.category = c.cat_name
SET d.cat_match_id = c.id;
```

Your current attempt is updating the `Category.category` field, which is already populated, and is what you were using in the join condition.

Note that I introduced aliases into your update query, which leaves it easier to read and more concise.

Comment: Thanks. I'm wondering if there is an issue with my data. I get no errors running this query, but still get no data returned. The columns being compared are the same variable type, spelling is all correct, there are no extra spaces. I'll try dropping the tables and re-populating the data to make sure I didn't accidentally change something after I first populated the tables.

Comment: Fixed it. It was my data (the c.id column) that was causing issues. Reworked some of it and plugged in your solution and it worked. Thanks!